# How to save sessionId of first login and doesn't make me login every time in inappwebview flutter

Tags: flutter, webview, flutterwebviewplugin, flutter-inappwebview

I want to write an application that makes me register from app and send post request and get response to inappwebview just like exam below

```dart
InAppWebView(
  initialUrl: widget.initUrls,
  initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
  crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
      mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
      debuggingEnabled: true,
    ),
  ),
  onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController c){
    _controller = c;
    if(staticEmail != null && staticPass != null) {
      _controller.postUrl(url: "https://xxxxxxx.com/my-account", postData: utf8.encode(
          "email=${staticEmail}&password=${staticPass}&wooc_user_phone=${staticShop}&wooc_user_name=${staticShop}&woocommerce-register-nonce=5d1b626841&_wp_http_referer=/my-account/&register=Register") )
          .whenComplete(() => {print("done")}).catchError((err){print("err : ${err}");
            isloading = false;
          });
    }
  },
);
```

and it login fine.

But when I go to another link or when I close app and login again it ask me to login again i just want to save cookie or session id that doesn't make me login every time

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [`CookieManager`](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/blob/master/README.md#cookiemanager-class) of this `flutter_inappwebview` package to get and set cookies. This is a singleton that the plugin uses, you can access it via:

```
CookieManager.instance()
```

Comment: Can you explain how to use it with my code

Comment: Based on the small code snippet you provided that's really hard. I'd suggest checking the content of `CookieManager.instance().getCookies()` when you close and/or open the in-app webview to figure out what works best for your use case.

Comment: i try cookieManager and save cookie inside sharedpreference and call it onwebviewcreated but also not work